# How can I unhex and make case-insensitive search in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, hex, sql-like, case-insensitive

I am having some data in column Name `MYDATA` that is in HEX format. I want to do a case-insensitive search for keywords (eg:absent) and get the results in `UNHex` format. I am using below statement:

```
 SELECT ADDRESS , DESTINATION , UNHEX(MYDATA) FROM DataBaseName.TableName
 WHERE LOWER(UNHEX(MYDATA)) LIKE LOWER('%absent%')
```

Problem: The statement get accepted in query with no errors but returns zero records. Where as there is data with keywords similar to ABSENT and Absent in the database specified.

Comment: `SELECT LOWER(UNHEX(MYDATA)) LIKE LOWER('%absent%') FROM DataBaseName.TableName ;` Just try this query.If it's return 1 anywhere in output?

Comment: If it's return 1 then definitely this query work fine.

Comment: it only returns 0 - not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ADDRESS , DESTINATION , CAST(UNHEX(MYDATA) AS CHAR) FROM DataBaseName.TableName WHERE LOWER(CAST(UNHEX(MYDATA) AS CHAR)) LIKE '%absent%'
```

Try above query. As mentioned in answer, you can try using **`CAST`**.

Comment: sir above statement i have tried, it does not make th search can insensitive and fetches zero results.(as actual unhex(MYDATA) has Absent and ABSENT and not absent.